# Can I create alias routes using react router?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, react-router

I am working on a new project to be built using react and react-router. I am planning to restructure my routes in such a way that it is cleaner than before. However, I don't want to break older bookmarks that users may have.

For instance, my new routes might look like:

```
    <Route  path="/" component={Layout}>
        <Route component={ItemList} path="items/:category"  />
        <Route component={ItemDetail} path="item/:designCode" />
    </Route>
```

Some example routes could be, say - /items/electronics, /items/gifts.

However, I have a legacy code base that had routes of the kind - /electronic-items, /buy-gifts, etc.

Is there a way I can create route aliases to be able to map these legacy URLs to the newly structured ones?

I have come across [something similar in Vue 2.0](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html), but am particularly interested in a react solution. Any suggestions (apart from - use redirects or use Vue itself instead :D)?

Comment: Neither the accepted answer, nor the other one don't seem to work anymore with RR@v6. Since v6, the Navigate component is used. Read more here: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#navigate

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am using react-router-dom v4.3.1 and as of this version multiple paths can be provided as an array to the path prop on the Route component like:

```
<Route path={["oldListUrl", "newListUrl"]} component={ItemList}/>
```

I believe this is much better than redirects. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that you're using `React-Router v4` you can use `Redirect` component like this:

```
<Route path="newListUrl" component={ItemList}/>
<Route path='/oldListUrl' render={() => (
    <Redirect to="newUrl" />
)}/>
```

If you're using `React-Router v3`:

```
<Route path="newListUrl" component={ItemList}/>
<Redirect from='oldListUrl'to="newListUrl" />
```

Comment: Thanks Bartek. I am not looking to do redirects (as mentioned in my question as well). Instead, I would like /oldListUrl and /newListUrl to be aliases of each other.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Can't you just define separate `Route` components for each URL (one for legacy URL and one for new)?

Comment: It looks to me that Bartek got it right the first time and that the OP is describing a redirect even though he doesn't think he is. And, yes, Bartek is right again in the comment that parallel routes would also work (but that's obviously not as correct as Bartek's first answer since it feels messier).

Comment: Nope. It's not the same thing, he's talking about serving the same component from different URLs.